# Determine the set of all values of $ x \in [0, 2 \pi] $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, trigonometry

> Determine the set of all values of $ x \in [0, 2 \pi] $ that simultaneously satisfy $ \frac {2 \sin ^ 2 x + \sin x-1} {\cos x-1} < 0 $ and $  \tan x + \sqrt {3} < (1+ \sqrt {3} \cot x) \cot x $

**My ''solution'':**

$\frac{2{{\sin }^{2}}x+\sin x-1}{\cos x-1}<0\Rightarrow 2{{\sin }^{2}}x+\sin x-1>0\Rightarrow \sin x\in \left( \frac{1}{2},1 \right]$ and $\tan x+\sqrt{3}<(1+\sqrt{3}\cot x)\cot x\Leftrightarrow \tan x+\sqrt{3}<\frac{\tan x+\sqrt{3}}{\tan x}\cot x\Leftrightarrow \tan x+\sqrt{3}<\left( \tan x+\sqrt{3} \right)\frac{{{\cos }^{2}}x}{{{\sin }^{2}}x}$

---

Am I right? Is there any better approach?

Comment: Your answer seems correct, but your presentation is awful. It's hard to read and follow. You refer to a first part and a second part, which the reader assumes to be the two inequalities defined at the top, but you seem to work out the second one twice. You then refer to the "first" and "second" inequality, which is unclear since we now have four inequalities in play. Do you mean the "first" first, or the "second" first? Also, defining p as cot(x) is not helpful. Furthermore, it does not clearly follow what you say follows. That's a major part you're skipping.

Comment: @Peatherfed I gave a corrected

Comment: @MeuluElisson The identity $$1+\tan^2x=\cot^2x$$ may help simplify the second inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality,

$$ \frac {2 \sin ^ 2 x + \sin x-1} {\cos x-1}=\frac{(2\sin x -1)(\sin x+1)}{ \cos x-1}< 0 $$
Then,
$\sin x+1>0,\>\>\>\cos x-1<0 \implies \sin x > \frac12\implies x\in (\frac \pi6,\frac{5\pi}6)\tag{1}$

The second inequality,

$$\tan x+\sqrt{3}<\left( \tan x+\sqrt{3} \right)\cot^2x$$
Case 1.

$\tan x+\sqrt{3}>0,\>\>\>\cot^2x>1 \implies 
x\in (0,\frac\pi4),\>(\frac{3\pi}4,\frac{5\pi}4),\>(\frac{7\pi}4,2\pi)\tag{2}$

Case 2.

$\tan x+\sqrt{3}<0,\>\>\>\cot^2x<1 \implies 
x\in (\frac{\pi}2,\frac{2\pi}3),\>(\frac{3\pi}2,\frac{5\pi}3)\tag{3}$

Combine (2) and (3),

$x \in (0,\frac\pi4),(\frac\pi2,\frac{2\pi}3),(\frac{3\pi}4,\frac{5\pi}4),(\frac{3\pi}2,\frac{5\pi}3),(\frac{7\pi}4,2\pi)\tag{4}$

Thus, from (1) and (4), determine the set of all values

$$x \in (\frac\pi6,\frac\pi4),(\frac\pi2,\frac{2\pi}3),(\frac{3\pi}4,\frac{5\pi}6)$$